# Adding elements at runtime and executing a jmeter test plan

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to build a jmeter testplan, where all the test values are sent from a csv datafile.I want to add assertions(provided in the datafile) to my HTTP Request at **runtime** and execute the test. The reason behind doing this is to keep the plan flexible according to the number of assertions. In my case, the assertions are getting added at the runtime; however they fail to get executed. May I know **what should be done to get the components added and executed in the same flow**?
**For example:** A part of plan looks like:

XYZ
  --HTTP Sampler
     -- Response Assertion1
     -- Response Assertion2
     -- JSON Extractor

where XYZ -->keyword based transaction controller(reusable component) 
Everytime I have  a request of type XYZ, this chunk of components will get executed. In my case, I do not want to place anything such as Assertions, pre/post processors, extractors in the test plan already. I want to generate these components at run time and execute them (as per my test requisites).

**Issue:** The problem here is that **I cant load the components programmatically and execute them in the same flow**. The reason being, the compiler does not know beforehand what all components it needs to execute, so it bypasses the newly added components.

So, I need some alternative solution to execute this.

Comment: This is too broad. Can you give example of a use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Response Assertion (or multiple) with Pattern to test filled with a variable as `${testAssert1}` and set the variable by default as empty, for example
Put in `User Defined Variables` name testAssert1 with empty value.

Your assertion(s) will pass until you on run time set the variable with a different value, for example using `User Parameters` Pre Processor.